# Fallo al integrar dependencia para pasarela de pago, error "Failed to Resolve: com.github"

Tags: android

Es mi primera app después de mis estudios, intento hacer una app para domicilios, ya esta todo hecho salvo el paso final, integrar pasarela de pagos (epayco) tienen su [SDK](https://github.com/epayco/epayco-android). Descargo e instalo las dependencias tal cual dicen los paso pero arroja el error en la imagen[image: Error al sincronizar D[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3DwO.png)

Agradezco su ayuda, como ya les dije es mi primer proyecto así que no se como instalarlo por completo y empezar a recibir pagos así que si alguien que sepa integrar este SDK a mi proyecto.

Comment: Recuerda leer [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Añade tu código, en este caso parte del gradle que te da error, etc caso contrario se dificulta encontrar el problema.

Comment: agregaste maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } a tus repositorios?

Comment: si ya lo he hecho, allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener dependencias de una library de github debes agregar dentro del archivo `build.gradle` del proyecto la declaración:

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

en `repositories` de `allprojects`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

...
```

Es importante definir correctamente la versión, que debe ser 1.01 :

```
 compile 'com.github.epayco:epayco-android:1.01'
```

hasta el día de hoy (Marzo 2018) solo se tienen las versiones 1.0 y 1.01 :

https://github.com/epayco/epayco-android/tags

Si no existe la versión en el repositorio, obtendrás el error:

> Error:( , ) Failed to resolve:

Comment: Pero claro, tenia mal la versión y no lo había notado, Gracias.

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.